# Could not found load model sale/order OpenCart

Tags: php, opencart

Suddenly I started to recieve the below error when tring to access mysite.com/admin

There are no solutions on the internet, so I kindly request your help on how to solve this

> ```
> Notice: Error: Could not load model sale/order! in /home/hirdavatdeposu.com/httpdocs/system/engine/loader.php on line 48
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re upload the file (unsure as to which it is, so just upload both) from a fresh copy

```
/catalog/model/sale/order.php
/admin/model/sale/order.php
```

Comment: Not the answer which fixed my problem but I guess that would be an answer to a similar problem, my problem arised becuase of an unexpected file that is uploaded to an unexpected page in ftp.